# How do i center a text field horizontaly and vertically in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi i am new to flutter i need to align the text field horizontally and vertically  for more elaboration see this

What i am getting:

Text aligned at the very top it needs to be in the center

[image]

What i really want:

the text field is aligned both horizontaly and vertically that is exactly what i am looing for

[image]

Here is the code:

```html
    import 'package:multi_purpose_scope/Animation/FadeAnimation.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: HomePage(),
      )
    );
    class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
    gotoSecondActivity(BuildContext context){
   Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondActivity()),
    );
   }
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
   body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {
    gotoSecondActivity(context);
        },
    child: Container(
    child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
    Container(
   height: 400,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
    image: AssetImage('assets/images/loginHeader.png'),
        fit: BoxFit.fill
            )
        ),
        child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
        ],
    ),
        ),
            Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
    FadeAnimation(1.8, Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
     color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    boxShadow: [
    BoxShadow(
     color: Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .2),
      blurRadius: 20.0,
        offset: Offset(0, 10)
            )
            ]
        ),
        child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.grey[100]))
        ),
    child: TextField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    hintText: "Email or Phone number",
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
color: Colors.grey[400])
   ),
    ),
   ),
    Container(
   padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: TextField(
    obscureText: true,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
  hintText: "Password",
  hintStyle: TextStyle(
  color: Colors.grey[400])
    ),
    ),
    )
   ],
   ),
    )),
     SizedBox(height: 30,),
     FadeAnimation(2, Container(
        height: 50,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [
            Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
    Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
                ]
    )
   ),
    child: Center(
    child: Text("Login", style: TextStyle(
   color: Colors.white,
 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
    ),
    )),
   SizedBox(height: 70,),
 FadeAnimation(1.5, Text("Forgot Password?",
 style: TextStyle(
    color: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1)),)),
    ],
   ),
   )
   ],
  ),
),
   )
),
        );
   }
  }
    class SecondActivity extends StatelessWidget {
        gotoRegister(BuildContext context){
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>Register()),
            );
        }
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return MaterialApp(
                home: Scaffold(
                    body: Container(
                        child: Container(
    height: 174,
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/patient_list.png'),
        )
    ),
   child: Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
        Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        height: 128,
    child: Text(
   'Patient List',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 30,
        color: Colors.white
  ),
   ),
   )
        ],
   ),
  ),
   ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
    gotoRegister(context);
    },
   tooltip: 'Increment',
   child: Icon(Icons.add),
   backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27,1),
   ),
   ),
   );
   }
   }
   class Register extends StatelessWidget {
   goBack(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
   }
   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
    body: Container(
   child:Container(
  height: 174,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
image: DecorationImage(
 image: AssetImage('assets/images/patient_list.png'),
    )
   ),
  child: Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
   Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
height: 128,
 child: Text(
 'Registration
style: TextStyle(
   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 30,
    color: Colors.white
    ),
   )
),
    Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
     border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.grey[100]))
        ),
        child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        hintText: "Email or Phone number",
         hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey[400])
    ),
   ),
  ),
   ],
  ),
 ),
)
),
 );
  }
   }
```

I searched for this but cant seem to find the solution to my problem.
I have almost tried all the solutions that i can think of but those don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `textAlign` property to your `TextField` and also add a border in your decoration.

Sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                const SampleTextField(hintText: 'Enter Name'),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                const SampleTextField(hintText: 'Enter MR-Number'),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                const SampleTextField(hintText: 'Enter Phone Number'),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                const SampleTextField(hintText: 'Enter Hospital Name'),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  // materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  // visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text('Registration'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SampleTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const SampleTextField({
    this.controller,
    this.hintText = '',
  });

  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String hintText;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: const BorderSide(
            width: 1,
            color: Colors.black54,
          ),
        ),
        hintText: hintText,
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black54,
        ),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
      ),
      // textAlign: TextAlign.center,   // Align vertically and horizontally
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a stack widget so if you want to align and positioned your widget inside the stack see the below options

1. Wrap widget with **Positioned** widget if you want to change position
2. Wrap widget with **Align** widget for alignment

Check out this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgtPleVwxBQ) for how to use Positioned widget

Check out this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2E7yl3MwMk) for how to use Align widget